# Accessing a simplexml element within a simplexml element

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I think theres something more going on here but it looks like certain data available in the raw xml is unavailable to me after it gets set in the simplexml element via my soap call.

Here's the raw information I get back from the soap call (retrieved w/ soapUI), Please note the e_mail element in particular.

```
<GetSubscriberData_ByDrupal_IdResult><![CDATA[
    <SubscriberDataRoot>
        <SubscriberData>
            <city>MEDIA</city>
            <state>PA</state>
            <zip>19063-4112</zip>
            <country>USA</country>
            <phone>1231231244</phone>
            <e_mail>some_email@somewhere.com</e_mail>
        </SubscriberData>
    </SubscriberDataRoot>]]>
</GetSubscriberData_ByDrupal_IdResult>
```

and here is the SimpleXMLElement that I var_dump'd after it was yielded from my SoapClient call.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#26 (1) {
  ["SubscriberData"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#33 (29) {
    ["city"]=>
    string(5) "MEDIA"
    ["state"]=>
    string(2) "PA"
    ["zip"]=>
    string(10) "19063-4112"
    ["country"]=>
    string(3) "USA"
    ["phone"]=>
    string(10) "1231231234"
    ["e_mail"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#36 (0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I can access most of the data as expected with something akin to `$soap_data->SubscriberData->city` however notable the e_mail element is not available directly, its another `SimpleXMLElement`. I've tried iterating over it, using `asXML`, `__toString`, casting to a `(string)`..

(for instance...)

```
php> var_dump($acct->SubscriberData->e_mail);
object(SimpleXMLElement)#38 (0) {
}

php> var_dump($acct->SubscriberData->e_mail->asXML());
string(17) "<e_mail></e_mail>"

php> var_dump($acct->SubscriberData->e_mail->__toString());
string(0) ""

php> var_dump((string) $acct->SubscriberData->e_mail);
string(0) ""
```

but I can't access it like any of the other string valued elements. I want to be able to get the string value such as `$email = $acct->SubscriberData->e_mail` like the rest of the elements. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can test/reproduce your object structure without your soap stuff, but if I took the raw XML and tried to process it, I'd have to process the CDATA block separately.

```
$GetSubscriberData_ByDrupal_IdResult = simplexml_load_string($xmlSource);
$SubscriberDataRoot = simplexml_load_string((string) $GetSubscriberData_ByDrupal_IdResult);
$email = (string) $SubscriberDataRoot->SubscriberData->e_mail;
echo $email; // assigned to var just for demonstration
```

Comment: Evenn just parsing the inner XML I can't reproduce that `object(SimpleXMLElement)#36` situation